# How to find the product of a value * the unique number of times it occurs in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

Example if i have a list

[100,50,1,1,1,1]
I want it to output

100 * 1 + 5 * 1 + 1 * 4

Currently Im using a dictionary to do so.

```
 lst = [100, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100]


        total = 0 
        dic = {}

        for elem in lst:
            if not elem in dic:
                dic[elem] = total 
                #print(dic)
            else:

                dic[elem] += total + 1

output is alittle off 
{100: 1, 50: 0, 1: 3} 
100 actually comes twice, and 1 appears 4 times.
```

Comment: Do you actually need the dict or just the sum answer?

Answer (score 0):

So to get how many times you need to multiply each number, you can use the count method.

Knowing that, the problem then becomes looping through unique elements in the original list and then counting/multiplying them from the original list.

To get unique values, we can use a set!

```
lst = [100, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100]

unique, sum = set(lst), 0
for number in unique:
    sum += number * lst.count(number)

print(sum)
```

If you actually need the dictionary:

```
lst = [100, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100]

unique, unique_counts = set(lst), {}
for number in unique:
    unique_counts[number] = lst.count(number)

print(unique_counts)
```